# Table does not fit TexMaker

Tags: tables

My table has 25 columns I think and how can I make each column smaller and make the table fit on one page ?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{l|lllllllllllllllllllllllll p{10cm}}

    Shifts/Time & 8     & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7 \\
     \hline \hline

    A1    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    A2    & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    B1    & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    B2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    C1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    C2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    D1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    D2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    E1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    E2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    F1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    F2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    G1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    G2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    H1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0 \\
    H2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0 \\
    I1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    I2    & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\

    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Found something that worked for me use this
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

Answer (score 2):

Just reduce the font size, and also the inter-column space The last column didn't seem to need 10cm so I made that `l` to match the others.

[image]

Note `article` does not have a `9pt` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
 \small
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{l|llllllllllllllllllllllllll}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Shifts/\\Time\end{tabular}
& 8     & 9     & 10    & 11    & 12    & 13    & 14    & 15    & 16    & 17    & 18    & 19    & 20    & 21    & 22    & 23    & 24    & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7 \\
     \hline \hline

    A1    & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    A2    & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    B1    & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    B2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    C1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    C2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    D1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    D2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    E1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    E2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    F1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    F2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    G1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    G2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0 \\
    H1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 0 \\
    H2    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0 \\
    I1    & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\
    I2    & 1     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1 \\

    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind shifting one page of your document to landscape view, try the `sidewaystable` environment. You'll need to add the `rotating` package to your preamble.